# Stream every row coming from a Postgres function

Tags: postgresql, functions, filestream, client

This is the how the function definition looks:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function(foo NUMERIC) 
RETURNS SETOF my_type AS $$
DECLARE rec record;
BEGIN   
    FOR rec IN SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_table.bar > foo
    LOOP
        RETURN QUERY SELECT 
            my_scalar_function(rec.bar1),
            my_scalar_function(rec.bar2),
            my_scalar_function(rec.bar3);
    END LOOP;                                             
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

On the client i am trying to use a QueryStream from the pg-query-stream package:

```
pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
  if (err) throw err
  const query = new QueryStream('SELECT * FROM my_function($1);', [123])
  const stream = client.query(query)
  stream.on('end', ()=>{
    console.log('finished')
    done()
    process.exit(0)
  })
  stream.pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(process.stdout)
});
```

But still i am getting all rows at the end of the function and no intermediate rows. I would like to stream every row when it is calculated in the my_function.

Comment: If the javascript driver buffers the complete result then where is the benefit of a stream? The [repository](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/tree/master/packages/pg-query-stream) shows an example with the generate_series function: `const query = new QueryStream('SELECT * FROM generate_series(0, $1) num', [1000000])`

Answer (score 3):

> *Q: But still i am getting all rows at the end of the function and no
> intermediate rows*

Unfortunately these results are accumulated (as opposed to streamed) by the server-side implementation of `RETURN QUERY`. This is explicitly mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html):

> Note
> The current implementation of RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY stores the
> entire result set before returning from the function, as discussed
> above. That means that if a PL/pgSQL function produces a very large
> result set, performance might be poor: data will be written to disk to
> avoid memory exhaustion, but the function itself will not return until
> the entire result set has been generated. A future version of PL/pgSQL
> might allow users to define set-returning functions that do not have
> this limitation.

Comment: Great :) so no streaming.

Comment: Ah damn :( I just had a great use-case pop into my head even if it did block one thread/process and require some adjustments to timeouts